# How to detect when screen is locked when in iOS standalone web app?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, animate-cc

When opening page in Safari mobile browser, I managed to use `document.hidden` to pause looped background music.

But when saved on the home screen and used as a standalone web app for fullscreen mode, the sound still keeps on looping even when the screen is locked.

I've managed to find and use this code to detect if the page is opened as a standalone web app:

```
if (("standalone" in window.navigator) && window.navigator.standalone == true) {
    // Code to detect screen is locked?
}
```

Nothing seems to be working for me though. Any one know a way?